# Angular 8 Module wise load external CSS/SCSS

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a two LAZY Loaded modules in angular 8 app, **Admin** and **User**.

Now there are few sets of **css/scss** like (bootstrap and some admin dashboard scss file) which i want to load only when the admin module's component is loaded in browser.

Can anyone please help with this.

Thanks